# How do you make the overflow icon visible on Android API 11 Honeycomb?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I just created a custom res/values/styles.xml file so that my ActionBar has no icon and no title, and also specifies a custom overflow icon.  It looks good on Android 4.0+, but when I run it on an Android 3.0 emulator, the overflow icon has disappeared.  By "disappeared" I mean that not only can I not see it, but I can't click on it either (so it's not as though it's just "blending in" - it's just not there at all!).

Here is the res/values/styles.xml that I'm working with:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">


    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">


    </style>


    <style name="CustomAppTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarWithoutTitleAndIcon</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomOverflowButton</item>
    </style>    

    <style name="CustomActionBarWithoutTitleAndIcon" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomOverflowButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_overflow</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Does anyone know how to make the overflow icon visible again on Honeycomb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not showing because you are testing it on a devices with `menu hardware key`

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) is saying:

```
The overflow icon only appears on phones that have no menu hardware keys. 
Phones with menu keys display the action overflow when the user presses the key.
```